# Does Objective-C support #elifdef?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I can't seem to get `#elifdef` to work in my iOS project.  If I do this:

```
#ifdef X
const Foo bar[] = { ... };
#else
const Foo bar[] = { ,,, };
#endif
```

Then the top one (under X) gets highlighted and the bottom one doesn't.  If I do this:

```
#ifdef W
const Foo bar[] = { ;;; };
#elifdef X
const Foo bar[] = { ... };
#else
const Foo bar[] = { ,,, };
#endif
```

Then the bottom one (under else) gets highlighted and the top two don't.  Why?  Is there another way I should be doing this?  I have three targets and they all use the same m file.  However, the constants are a bit different for each target so I separate them this way.

Comment: I've never used that pre-process command; I've always used `#elif defined(THING)`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks!  That did it!  I know almost nothing about preprocessor commands, but a google search turned up lots of people using #elifdef so I tried to use it.

Comment: I know I'm about 11 years late, but `#elifdef` is finally a thing in C23 (Xcode 13.3 or later).

Comment: @Bbrk24 Hah!  Classic.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
#elif defined X
```

Which should be compatible with all ANSI-C compatible compilers.

Comment: Excellent!  I'm too young to have experienced C, so I don't know about a lot of this stuff ><.  I also didn't quite know the query I should search for on Google.  It won't let me accept your answer for 9 minutes, but I'll be back.

Comment: And I will now eat my foot as I see you are the same age as me... >_<

Comment: You're too young to have experienced the *creation* of C. Nobody is too young to learn it.

Comment: @Dave Right, what I meant was I was too young to have used C in its heyday.  I learned some elementary C in college but I never had any real world use.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `#elif defined(X)` to avoid potential syntax issures?